# pause/ play a game in cocos2d android?

Tags: cocos2d-android

How to pause a game in cocos2d android? I searched many tutorials but i did not found anywhere.I tried below code, it is working when paused from game scene.But it not working while resuming the game from pause scene

in gameScene :

```
CCDirector.sharedDirector().onPause();
```

in pause Scene :

```
   CCDirector.sharedDirector().onResume();
```

Answer (score 1):

For pausing game scene I use:

```
CCDirector.sharedDirector().pause();
```

And for resuming:

```
CCDirector.sharedDirector().resume();
```

Try it with these functions. :)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for  your reply. I used the same thing.But it wont stop schedulers and actions.
But finally i got the way we have to pause.

1.To pause we have to use pushScene()  method as follows:

```
CCScene pauseScene = CCScene.node();
pauseScene.addChild(new PauseLayer);
CCDirector.sharedDirector().pushScene(pauseScene);
```

When you have done this, gamescene  will get stored in the stack and now running scene will be pause scene.

2.To resume we have to use popScene() as follows:

```
    CCDirector.sharedDirector().popScene();
```

3.If you are moving to LevelSelection form pause then along with above lines use these lines also:

```
 CCDirector.sharedDirector().getRunningScene().removeAllChildren(true);
    CCDirector.sharedDirector().replaceScene(levelSelectScene);
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare a `BOOL` variable, then when you detect user pauses game, make this variable to `NO` and in your update method put this as a condition above to the code you want to pause on your game paused.

```
-(void)update:(ccTime)dt
{
  if(isGameNotPaused)
  {
     // your code

  }
}
```